# How to create simple browser with Mozilla ActiveX Control with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, browser, activex, mozilla

I download and install [Mozilla ActiveX Control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm#download)

and add `MozillaBrowser Class` to ToolBox

Create a windows form application windows, drag drop `MozillaBrowser` from ToolBox to `Form1`

also drag drop a `WebBrowser1` to `Form1`

in `Form1_Load` write this:

```
WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance = AxMozillaBrowser1
```

but Error Property 'ActiveXInstance' is 'ReadOnly'.

I want display a fix URL in Mozilla browser, Now I must what to do?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it this control is a direct *replacement* for the WebBrowser control so you should just add an instance of the control on your form and then something like this should work:

```
AxMozillaBrowser1.Navigate2("http://www.bbc.co.uk")
```

have a look at this wrapper which may help you on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20312/Browsers-Wrapper-Mozilla-IE