# Replace WebBrowser control in VS2019 with Mozilla browser control (v1.7.12)

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have looked at numerous posts that discuss embedding the Mozilla browser control in a VB.NET app, however they were all written many years ago and are incomplete, like: [How to create simple browser with Mozilla ActiveX Control with VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336945/how-to-create-simple-browser-with-mozilla-activex-control-with-vb-net).

I was able to have a little success (display an HTML file with CSS3 and JavaScript) by embedding cefSharp into my VB.NET app, but cefSharp adds hundreds of MB. One of the posts said they believed that the Mozilla browser control (v1.7.12) was an exact replacement for the VS 2019 .Net web browser control, but there was no information on how to make the switch. Please advise if the Mozilla browser control is a good alternative, and if so, point to a tutorial or other information for making it work...or is there another choice?

Answer (score 0):

You must use 3rd party library for this. You can use either [GeckoFx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/src/default/) for Firefox engine, or [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) for Chrome engine.